# Creating a Function That Automaticaly Knows Whether to Insert or Update in Flask, SqlAlchemy, Python

Tags: python, mysql, flask-sqlalchemy

I currently have two seperate sections of code, one that inserts an entirely new row into mySQL database. The second one just updates a row if it already exists.

I am trying to combine these two into one function that automatically checks if the id is in the table, and if so updates, otherwise inserts a new row? This is what I have so far:

```
class Example(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'schools'
        _id = db.Column('_id', db.Unicode, primary_key=True)
        establishmentNumber = db.Column('establishmentNumber', db.Unicode)
        laCode = db.Column('laCode', db.Unicode)
        urn = db.Column('urn', db.Unicode)
        name = db.Column('name', db.Unicode)
        phaseOfEducation = db.Column('phaseOfEducation', db.Unicode)
        wondeID = db.Column('wondeID', db.Unicode)

        def __init__(self, _id, establishmentNumber, laCode, urn, name, phaseOfEducation, wondeID):
            self._id = _id
            self.establishmentNumber = establishmentNumber
            self.laCode = laCode
            self.urn = urn
            self.name = name
            self.phaseOfEducation = phaseOfEducation
            self.wondeID = wondeID

            def add_or_update(cls, _id, establishmentNumber, laCode, urn, name, phaseOfEducation, wondeID):
                entity = cls.query.filter_by(_id=school._id.iloc[0]).first()
                print(entity)

                if not entity:
                    entity = cls(school._id.iloc[0], school.establishmentNumber.iloc[0], school.laCode.iloc[0], school.urn.iloc[0], school.name.iloc[0], school.phaseOfEducation.iloc[0], school.wondeID.iloc[0])
                    db.session.add(entity)
                    db.session.commit()

                else:
                    entity.establishmentNumber = 'hello'
                    db.session.commit()
                    print (entity.establishmentNumber)

                return entity
```

It doesn't produce any errors, but it also doesn't add or update either. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have indentation error. Reindent like:

```
def __init__(self, _id, establishmentNumber, laCode, urn, name, phaseOfEducation, wondeID):
    self._id = _id
    self.establishmentNumber = establishmentNumber
    self.laCode = laCode
    self.urn = urn
    self.name = name
    self.phaseOfEducation = phaseOfEducation
    self.wondeID = wondeID

@classmethod
def add_or_update(cls, _id, establishmentNumber, laCode, urn, name, phaseOfEducation, wondeID):
    entity = cls.query.filter_by(_id=school._id.iloc[0]).first()
    print(entity)

    if not entity:
        entity = cls(school._id.iloc[0], school.establishmentNumber.iloc[0], school.laCode.iloc[0],
                     school.urn.iloc[0], school.name.iloc[0], school.phaseOfEducation.iloc[0],
                     school.wondeID.iloc[0])
        db.session.add(entity)
        db.session.commit()

    else:
        entity.establishmentNumber = 'hello'
        db.session.commit()
        print(entity.establishmentNumber)

    return entity
```

Comment: Thanks @IamMashed. I've just fixed the indentation. But it's still now working. No errors, but no add/update either

Comment: try adding @classmethod

Comment: Thanks @IamMashed - fixed now

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @IamMashed. It is working great now, but it is very slow. It takes 30 minutes to insert 150,000 rows. Do you know how I can speed it up? Is it how I'm committing it that's making it slow?